# How to show python image variable to html using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to show video frame image variable to HTML.
Here is my video code.

```py
def webcam(queue, capture):
  while True:
    frame_pos = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    frame_count = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

  (grabbed, frame) = capture.read()
  if not grabbed:
    print ("Not grabbed.")
    break;

  if((frame_pos%50) == 0):  
    results = model.detect([frame], verbose=1)

    # Visualize results
    r = results[0]
    masked_frame = display_instances(frame, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], class_names, r['scores'])
```

and this is flask code

```py
def threaded() -> 'html': 

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.route("/")
def home()-> 'html':
  return render_template('test.html')

app.run()
```

I used these 2 functions by using thread like this

```py
start_new_thread(threaded, ())

while True:
  start_new_thread(webcam(enclosure_queue,capture), (enclosure_queue,))
```

I want the local variable 'masked_frame' to flask function and show it to HTML web page.
But I don't know what to do...
Can I get the local image variable in flask function?
And how to connect that to HTML?
Please help me